# Multiple roots in the complex plane with R

Tags: r, complex-numbers

I've been trying to find a function that returns all complex solutions of an equation such as:

```
16^(1/4) = 2+i0,  -2+i0,  0+i2,  0-i2
```

As it stands, if I enter `16^(1/4)` into the console, it only returns 2.  I can write a function for this but I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this in R.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `polyroot()`:

```
polyroot(z = c(-16,0,0,0,1))
# [1]  0+2i -2-0i  0-2i  2+0i
```

Where `z` is a "vector of polynomial coefficients in increasing order".

The vector I passed to `z` in the example above is a compact representation of this equation:

```
-16x^0 + 0x^1 + 0x^2 + 0x^3 + 1x^4 = 0

                          x^4 - 16 = 0

                               x^4 = 16

                                 x = 16^(1/4)
```

---

**Edit:**

If `polyroot`'s syntax bothers you, you just could write a wrapper function that presents you with a nicer (if less versatile) interface:

```
nRoot <- function(x, root) {
    polyroot(c(-x, rep(0, root-1), 1))
}
nRoot(16, 4)
# [1]  0+2i -2-0i  0-2i  2+0i
nRoot(16, 8)
# [1]  1.000000+1.000000i -1.000000+1.000000i -1.000000-1.000000i
# [4]  1.000000-1.000000i  0.000000+1.414214i -1.414214-0.000000i
# [7]  0.000000-1.414214i  1.414214+0.000000i
```

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks a ton.. But I'm not too fond of the syntax.

Comment: @NathanG -- I added something that'll likely be more to your liking.